# Ember not calling setupController of router

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

So, I have two paths in my route. I created the two routes as the [doc recommends](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/redirection/#toc_transitioning-after-the-model-is-known).

My router is the following:

```
// router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('photos');
  this.route('photo', { path: '/photo/:photo_id' });
});
```

If I visit firstly the route /photo/ID and then go to /photos, it will only show one object on the latter. (**wrong**)

If I visit /photos first it shows all the objects and I can go to /photo/ID later on and it will be fine. (**right**)

I want to make it work both ways. How to do this? You can see my code for each route down below:

```
// photo.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('photo', params.photo_id);
  }
});

// photos.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController(controller, model) {
    let photos = this.get('store').findAll('photo');
    console.log('add all...');
    // convert to an array so I can modify it later
    photos.then(()=> {
      controller.set('photos', photos.toArray());
    });
  },
});
```

I can always call the `findAll()` function regardless where the user goes, but I don't think this is smart.

The way I am dealing with the page transitions:

To go to photos I use:

```
{{#link-to 'photos'}}All{{/link-to}}
```

To go to /photo/ID I inject the service '-routing' and I use in one event click like this:

```
routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),
actions() {
    selectRow(row) {
        this.get("routing").transitionTo('photo', [row.get('id')]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling link-to for transitioning ?. if you provide `model` or any object then it will not call model hook and setupController hook

Comment: I will add to the question, because it was getting weird here in the comments

Comment: Could it be because you're not setting model() in photos.js therefore your Model isn't updated?

Comment: I'm not sure. I will try

Comment: You can try `let photos = this.get('store').findAll('photo',{reload:true})`. this will wait for the server to return the data and update it in store and then it will set it to `photos` property

Comment: I'm not the most experienced Ember Developer, but why are you setting up the `photos` in the variable inside of `setupController`, wouldn't it be better to return it with the Model?

Comment: I'm doing that now, @Cameron. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll` will get it from a store and return immediately and later on it will request the server and update the store. but in your case, as you are not using route model hook, so this live array will not be updated so it will not reflect it in the template.

> If I visit firstly the route /photo/ID and then go to /photos, it will
>   only show one object on the latter.

In the above case, store will contain only one reocrd, so when you ask for store data using `findAll` it will return the existing single record.

Another option is,
avoiding this `photos.toArray()` - It will break live-array update, I am not sure why do you need it here. since `photos` is `DS.RecordArray`.

> Note: It's important to note that DS.RecordArray is not a JavaScript
>   array, it's an object that implements Ember.Enumerable. This is
>   important because, for example, if you want to retrieve records by
>   index, the [] notation will not work--you'll have to use
>   objectAt(index) instead.

Comment: Great! This works! Thanks! I think I might need to create one thing to check whether all the data was already inserted or not... otherwise it will always search for all the photos even though they might be in the store already